# Prove the inequality: $a^2+b^2+1≥ab+a+b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics, discriminant, sum-of-squares-method

Prove the inequality.

$a^2+b^2+1≥ab+a+b$

I try so many methods, But I have not been successful in any way.Because, I can not find *"hint".*

Comment: what Kind of numbers are $a,b,c$?

Comment: For any numbers....

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner There is no $c$ there. It's valid for any real $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$a^2+b^2+1-ab-a-b=\frac{1}{2}((a-b)^2+(a-1)^2+(b-1)^2)\geq0$$

Answer (score 7):

This is the $c=1$ case of
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+ac+bc.$$
One only needs to prove this for $a$, $b$, $c\ge0$.

Comment: It's true for all $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

If $b=1$ it becomes $a^2-2a+1\ge 0$
which is true.
assume $b\ne 1$.

It is equivalent to prove that
$$a^2-a (b+1)+b^2+1-b>0$$

$$\Delta=b^2+2b+1-4b^2-4+4b $$
$$=-3(b^2-2b+1)=-3 (b-1)^2<0$$
Done.

Comment: very nice solution

Comment: @Leox Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Move all to left: $$a^2+b^2+1-ab-a-b\ge 0$$

Find the minimum value of $f(a,b)=a^2+b^2+1-ab-a-b$ using partial differentiation:

$f_a=2a-b-1=0$

$f_b=2b-a-1=0$

$a=b=1$

$f_{aa}=2>0, f_{bb}=2>0, f_{aa}f_{bb}-f_{ab}^2=3>0 \Rightarrow f(1,1)=0$ is minimum.

Comment: The function is continuous and there are no other critical points. It implies there can be no other turning points, consequently the functional value cannot get lower than this local minimum, therefore it is global minimum.

Answer (score 1):

All of the quantities on the left are $+ve$ ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
(a-b)^2+(a-1)^2+(b-1)^2 \geq 0
\end{eqnarray*}
divide by $2$ & rearrange ... the inequality follows.